# Why my else condition is never executing?

Tags: c++, udp

I am working on UDP server and this code of UDP server is working fine except the else condition. May be i am wrong but i have done lot of things using else condition in the same way to terminate while loop. I am not sure if its UDP problem or something else........

```
while(1)// execute three times because its getting data only three times from the client
    {
    int total_bytes = 0;
    int bytes_recv=0;
    int count = 0;
    std::vector<double> m_vector(8000);

        // Bytes are also received 3 times correctly then why else condition not executing after receiving 3 times ?
         bytes_recv = recvfrom(Socket,(char*)m_vector.data(),64000,0,(SOCKADDR*)&ClientAddr,&i);
        count++;

        if(bytes_recv > 0 )
        {
            total_bytes = total_bytes+bytes_recv;
            std::cout<<"Server: loop counter is"<<count<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Server: Received bytes are"<<total_bytes<<std::endl;
        }else

        {
        //why this part  never executes ? 
            std::cout<<"Data Receiving has finished"<<std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    WSACleanup();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment in the source says that you expect only 3 datagrams from the client. Thus, do count how many datagrams you have received, and if you already have 3 of them, *do not continue calling* `recvfrom`.
You already have a variable `count`, but it is reset to zero every iteration and isn't used as exit condition.

Once you have `count == 3`, you *know*  that there is nothing more coming, so calling `recvfrom` is pointless. It will only block, since that is what you're telling it to do. Making the socket non-blocking would "help" to avoid blocking, but then you would be polling, which isn't good either (and useless, since you *know* there is nothing to be received). It's best to operate *correctly*.

You could also have the client send an "end of message" datagram, but of course you would have to add a timeout and a strategy for packet loss, or the server could block *forever*. Not only because of malicious clients, but also simply because the receive buffer was full and a packet was dropped (which is a normal thing to happen!).

Alternatively, since there is a call to `WSACleanup` in your code, you're using Winsock. Which means you *could* use overlapped `WSARecvFrom` instead of `recvfrom`. Fire off one receive, and from its completion handler fire off another two, also with a callback function. After firing off the request, forget about it and let the callback handle the rest, you can now deal with another client (must be alertable though for that to happen ... alternatively, block on an IOCP or `WaitOnMultipleObjects` or whatever).
If no second or third packet comes in after so and so long, either send a "please resend" message or consider the client dead, close the socket and move on.

Comment: I found this as a solution because i dont want to use non blocking recv(). I am not able to figure out where i put this in my code ?  `struct timeval tv;
  tv.tv_usec = 100000;
  if (setsockopt(rcv_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,&tv,sizeof(tv)) < 0)`

Comment: That will "work" too, but why do you want to block for some milliseconds _waiting for no datagrams to arrive_ when there is no reason to do so? You should really operate _correctly_, not in a "it kinda works" way. Also, do note that the code you posted is for Unix-like systems, the argument for `SO_RCVTIMEO` must be **`DWORD`** under Windows, not `timeval` (and _milli_, not microseconds). You would insert that code before doing the first call to `recvfrom`.

Answer (score 0):

recvfrom is by default a blocking call and will only return once a packet has been read. Because of this when you stop sending packets it just blocks on recvfrom so the case with 0 bytes never happens

You could change the flags to recvfrom to change this behaviour, but it's likely not what you want because then if there's any delay between sending the packets you will get 0 bytes and exit.

I suppose you could see how long you've gone without receiving any packets and then shut down, so in the else case you could use a timer and a running total before exiting.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Whats the other way to terminate this while loop, any idea ?

Comment: Simply change the `while(1)` to `while(iAmSureIWantToKeepLooping)`, keep that variable `true` by default and set that variable to `false` when your program thinks it's time to quit.

Comment: If you have the option, try using poison pill technique. Send special packet from client, to notify server about end of communication.

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked (bad me, I know, but time's short), if `recvfrom` follows typical behavior, then it guarantees you that:

- returns value < 0 means error
- returns value == 0 means that everything was OK but channel cannot receive anything more
- returns value > 0 means something was received

In TCP you get 'received bytes' == 0 only when the connection is closed.

In UDP there's no such thing as 'connection'. The channel is always ready to receive, until **your** the socked is closed.

Hence, it probably simply waits until something arrives. It cannot detect that there is noone to listen from. That's the UDP specifics.

If you want to catch a case when nothing arrives for a long time, try to set read timeout.